# three.js: Using BufferGeometry with circles (or other shapes)

Tags: performance, three.js

would it be possible to use bufferedgeometry filled with circles or other shapes? by circles i mean filled circles

i have tried drawing a circle via a series of "Line"s, but of course it wans't a filled circle, i have also tried using a ParticleCloud with pngs that looked like circles, but then the performance wouldn't be as good as native meshed circle i guess.

the closest i got to is when i drew a circle via a series of multiple "Mesh" objects but it is very cumbersome.

does BufferGeometry even support such thing?

Comment: What do you mean "filled with circles?" BufferGeometry is just a way of storing vertex/attribute data; if you wanted a bunch of meshes representing flat circles, you could in fact store them in a BufferGeometry. Also, why don't you think the performance of a particle system will be acceptable?

Comment: "filled circle", like circle with a fill; not lines in the circle shape. i already wrote that i tried to represent the circles with a bunch of mesh object, but it's really clumsy to draw a bunch of triangles manually in order to represent a circle. i know that buffergeometry supports lines, meshes, phongmeshes and particles; but didn't find anything out about circles.

and i thought that particlesystem wouldn't be as good because intuitively, rendering a bunch of 24 bit transparent pngs would probably a larger overload than some primitive meshes

Comment: It's crazy that this question is six years old and apparently still nobody found a way to do this... I just cannot imagine that it isn't possible to render a ParticleCloud of filled circles in ThreeJS, it seems like such a basic task.

Answer (score 0):

In three.js there is CircleBufferGeometry

```html
var geometry = new THREE.CircleBufferGeometry( 5, 32 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
var circle = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( circle );
```